# Approximating a distribution with an integer histogram

Tags: algorithms, distance, histogram, approximation, discrete-distributions

Given a distribution $f:[0,a)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, is there  a simple algorithm by which to find a sequence $\{h_i\in\mathbb{N_0}\}$ such that $f(x)$ is approximated by $h_{floor(x)}$ as a histogram approximation of a real distribution?

Note that both the domain and the codomain of the approximation are discretized.

"Approximated by" means something reasonable, such as:

- Best matching total: $\sum_ih_i=round(\int_0^af(x)dx)$
- (Subject to the above) Minimum earth mover's distance

#### My thoughts

I think I found it:

1. Define the cumulative distribution $F(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du$
2. Look up $H_i=round(F(i))$
3. Differentiate: $h_i=H_{i+1}-H_i$

Perhaps someone can tell me what distance this is minimizing i.e. what my question was supposed to ask?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "distribution:" would this be a probability density function (which seems likeliest), a cumulative distribution function, or possibly something else?  You ought to specify what you mean by "approximation" more clearly because the answer depends on it.  Don't leave it to readers to guess your question!

Comment: @whuber I'll try to clarify it. I suspect there may be very simple algorithms for some reasonable definitions, whereas if I introduce an arbitrary definition it may necessitate a complicated algorithm.

Comment: @whuber The total is already decided, so it's just a matter of shifting units along the discrete domain to minimize some distance between $f(x)$ and $h_{floor(x)}$. Can you recommend a distance that would be simple to optimize in this way?

Comment: It depends on your objective; you could use almost any reasonable metric to compare the two distributions.

Comment: @whuber I have a list of real observations, each of which is subject to some (say gaussian) error. I could simply bin them into a histogram, but I want to use the knowledge that they are subject to error, to produce a more repeatable "histogram". (And the result has to look just like a frequency histogram). So I first construct $f$ from all these little gaussian kernels. For example, if they are all just under a threshold, I want the population to straddle that threshold in the histogram rather than rounding them all down.

Comment: @whuber Maximum-likelihood histogram with noisy data. Should I ask that as a new question?